# Trace inequality with matrix square-roots

Tags: inequality, trace

Suppose I have symmetric matrices $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and $B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ which are both positive definite. I am wondering if I one can bound ${\rm tr}\left(A - B \right)$ in the following way:

\begin{align*}
{\rm tr}\left(A - B \right) & = {\rm tr}\left[ (A^{1/2} - B^{1/2})(A^{1/2} + B^{1/2}) \right] \\
& \leq {\rm tr}\left[ (A^{1/2} - B^{1/2})\right] f(A^{1/2} + B^{1/2}),
\end{align*}

for some function $f$, e.g., spectral norm? Does such an inequality exist?

In full generality, I cannot say anything about the sign of the eigenvalues of $A^{1/2} - B^{1/2}$, so as far as I can tell, many of the standard inequalities do not apply.

Any insight would be very helpful.

Edit: An example showing that such an inequality will fail in certain cases was suggested by Darij Grinberg in the comments below.

Comment: Your first inequality is bound to fail if $A = \operatorname{diag}(1, 16)$ and $B = \operatorname{diag}(4, 9)$, since the first factor on the RHS will just be $0$.

Answer (score 0):

One way to get your inequality: let $e_i$ be an orthonormal eigenbasis of $A^{1/2} + B^{1/2}$. We have
$$
{\rm tr}\left[ (A^{1/2} - B^{1/2})(A^{1/2} + B^{1/2}) \right] = 
\sum_{i=1}^n e_i^T(A^{1/2} - B^{1/2})(A^{1/2} + B^{1/2})e_i =\\
\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i e_i^T (A^{1/2} - B^{1/2}) e_i  \leq 
\sum_{i=1}^n \|A^{1/2} + B^{1/2}\| \, e_i^T (A^{1/2} - B^{1/2}) e_i =\\ 
\|A^{1/2} + B^{1/2}\| \operatorname{tr}(A^{1/2} - B^{1/2})
$$

---

Another inequality that may interest you: because $A,B \mapsto \operatorname{tr}(AB)$ forms an inner product over the symmetric matrices, we may use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to conclude that
$$
{\rm tr}\left[ (A^{1/2} - B^{1/2})(A^{1/2} + B^{1/2}) \right] \leq \sqrt{{\rm tr}[(A^{1/2} - B^{1/2})^2]} \sqrt{{\rm tr}[(A^{1/2} + B^{1/2})^2]}
$$

Comment: To clarify, here you use the $\|\cdot\|$ as the spectral norm?

Comment: Could be an issue on my end, but in small scale experiments, the first inequality is frequently violated. In general, $e_i'(A^{1/2} - B^{1/2})e_i$ could be negative, so I'm not sure  your $\leq$ argument holds. It would if $e_i'(A^{1/2} - B^{1/2})e_i$ was replaced with its absolute value.

Comment: Ah, you're right.  I'll leave the answer up in case you find it useful, but I probably won't find the time to fix it.